# How to setup DEV/PROD website on public IP

Tags: apache, ubuntu, configuration, development-environment, vhosts

This is for 
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I have a server with a certain IP address (example `22.22.22.22`). I want to setup a DEV, a TEST and PROD environment.

for example if I go, from any computer in the world 
1) to `http://22.22.22.22` then I  will hit the production website
2) to `http://22.22.22.22/dev` then I will hit the development website
3) to `http://22.22.22.22/test` then I will hit the testing website

How can I set this up?

Please share your suggestions and thoughts around this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for—I would take a slightly different approach. You will have a domain name, say `example.com`. You would have `www.example.com` and `example.com` point to your production site. Then you could have `dev.example.com` and `test.example.com` point to their respective sites. All of the DNS entries would still point to `22.22.22.22`, but you would set up Apache to deal with them differently. This uses Apache *named virtual hosts*.

On the standard install of Apache, the site configurations should be in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. To start with, there should be a configuration file named `default`. Create a new file `prod` with contents like the following:

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/prod
<VirtualHost 22.22.22.22:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/prod/html

    (etc.)

</VirtualHost>
```

I've got the basics there, but you can look at the `default` for other directives you'll want there.

Next you create files for `dev` and `test`. Like so:

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/dev
<VirtualHost 22.22.22.22:80>
    ServerName dev.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dev/html

    (etc.)

</VirtualHost>
```

It should be basically the same as `prod`, but different `DocumentRoot` and `ServerName`. The config for `test` will be almost the same too.

Once you have these set up, you just need to enable them. Run:

```
sudo a2ensite dev
```

...this enables `dev`. same thing again for `test`. After you run this, you should see the files are now also symlinked in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. (The `a2ensite` command creates the symlink.)

Next, you just restart Apache. One way is: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Thanks, Your response is very accurate, I have already done all the above you mentioned, the only issue is that I don't have a domain name yet on the IP. I will get that at some point, but for now I have to use the IP address. And IP must serve all 3 environments (dev, test and data) ultimately a subdomain is what I will go towards, but for now the IP is all I got.